# Как настроить xdg-open для открытия внешнего приложения по ссылке в браузере?

Tags: linux, mime

Моя проблема заключается в том, что ни один браузер в linux-mint не может открывать steam-ссылки (хотя другие внешние приложения открываются нормально).

Предположим, я хочу установить игру, нажимаю на соответствующую кнопку, и браузер пытается открыть ссылку наподобие "steam://run/449140" при помощи xdg-open. В результате получаем ошибку:

> gvfs-open: steam://run/449140: ошибка открытия адреса: Указанный адрес
>   не поддерживается

Но если запустить ту же ссылку через steam (`steam steam://run/449140`), то всё пройдёт успешно и откроется окно с установкой игры.

В общем, мне нужно как-то либо объяснить браузеру, что такие ссылки открываются при помощи steam, а не xdg, либо настроить xdg, чтобы тот запускал ссылку через steam.

Я пробовал гуглить этот вопрос и нашёл вот что: [How do I set a new xdg-open setting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62585/how-do-i-set-a-new-xdg-open-setting). Добавил при помощи gconf новую ветку /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/steam и настроил её, но это не помогло.

Возможно, мне нужно править файл `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, но я совершенно не соображаю как.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

на основании ответа: [How to tell Chrome what to do with a magnet link?](https://askubuntu.com/a/133693/416190)

создайте файл `~/.local/share/applications/steam.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=steam %U
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/steam
Name=steam launcher
```

и назначьте его обработчиком схемы `steam`:

```
$ xdg-mime default steam.desktop x-scheme-handler/steam
```

эта команда добавит нужную строчку в нужную секцию файла `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.

проверить текущее назначение можно так:

```
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/steam
```

команда должна вернуть то, что вы назначили:

```
steam.desktop
```

теперь проверьте работоспособность настройки:

```
 $ xdg-open steam://run/449140
```

это, по идее, должен быть полный эквивалент команды:

```
 $ steam steam://run/449140
```

---

если у вас не *gnome*, не *kde*, не *lxde*, и не *xfce*, то `xdg-open` не сработает. надо в этом файле (это скрипт оболочки, где именно он находится, можно узнать командой `which xdg-open`) заменить строку

```
DE=generic
```

на что-нибудь из перечисленного списка. например:

```
DE=gnome
```

---

p.s. наверняка из предложенного мною содержимого desktop-файла (это уже урезанное содержимое файла, который предлагался по приведённой ссылке) можно ещё пару-тройку строчек удалить. мне уже просто было лень тестировать.