# Как написать скипт, по которому приложение trueconf будет открываться по ссылке, минуя браузер (linux)

Tags: linux, mime

Появилась потребность в реализации возможности переходить по ссылке на конференцию в труконф сразу в приложение (ипа trueconf://... , а не https://...)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527908/178576

Comment: не получилось так

Comment: Ну так а `query` чё выдаёт? Ну то, которое в ответе по ссылке?

Answer (score 1):

Получить прямые ссылки "trueconf:" для подключения с помощью клиентских приложений можно с помощью API запроса Software_Clients – Get Client List как показано во 2 шаге статьи https://trueconf.ru/blog/baza-znaniy/kak-podklyuchit-gostya-k-konferenczii-napryamuyu.html#_2

Comment: вам стоило дополнить ваш предыдущий ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Можете ознакомиться с нашей статьей, там описаны все возможные форматы обращения к протоколу trueconf: https://trueconf.ru/blog/baza-znaniy/protokol-trueconf-dlya-vzaimodeystviya-s-klientskimi-prilozheniyami-trueconf.html. Если у вас возникнут ещё вопросы, обращайтесь в наш telegram-чат @trueconf_talks, там вам помогут наши специалисты и тех.поддержка.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)